# porting RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} from Apache2 to nginx

Tags: nginx

I made a static mirror of a large PHP-based website, using the following Apache2 rewrite stanzas gets the query string into the filesystem path to serve the static files correctly.  Old dynamic url `foo/?bar` maps to static file `foo/index.html@bar`, `foo/image.php?bar` maps to `foo/image.php@bar` - all with `/` replaced by `%2F` wherever it occurs in `bar` (which is at most 5 times in the original site).  To give an example, I have urls like `example.com/foo/?bar=baz/quux` which I need to map to files like `foo/index.html@bar=baz%2Fquux`.

```
# turn off php
php_admin_value engine off

# enable rewrites
RewriteEngine on

# rewrite .../?... to .../index.html@... with s|/|%2F|g

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html@%1 [L,T=text/html]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html@%1\%2F%2 [L,T=text/html]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html@%1\%2F%2\%2F%3 [L,T=text/html]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/index.html@%1\%2F%2\%2F%3\%2F%4 [L,T=text/html]

# rewrite .../image.php?... to .../image.php@... with s|/|%2F|g

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/image.php$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/image.php@%1 [L,T=image/jpeg]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/image.php$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/image.php@%1\%2F%2 [L,T=image/jpeg]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/image.php$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/image.php@%1\%2F%2\%2F%3 [L,T=image/jpeg]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/image.php$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/image.php@%1\%2F%2\%2F%3\%2F%4 [L,T=image/jpeg]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/image.php$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/image.php@%1\%2F%2\%2F%3\%2F%4\%2F%5 [L,T=image/jpeg]
```

The Apache2 config above works fine, but we are migrating to nginx, which I'm having trouble configuring for this use case.  I can think of a couple of workarounds, the first is using a huge `map` directive listing all the urls on the site (undesirable due to size), the second is writing a small custom cgi script (undesireable as this is intended to be a static mirror).

> Is there an elegant solution?

(Renaming all the files on the filesystem is an option, if it would make things easier, though I don't see how, but changing the browser-facing URLs isn't possible.)

Comment: maybe check here :http://serverfault.com/questions/425704/convert-from-apache-rewrite-to-nginx
it seems that http://winginx.com/en/htaccess solved the issue, maybe that can help you with some of yours

Comment: @pat unfortunately that site doesn't translate the rewrites correctly - I get a literal %1 etc in the filename instead of the correct part of the Apache2 RewriteCond regexp

Answer (score 0):

Isn't something like this going to work for the first 4 ?
You have to put them in the reverse order so that the more global location don't match the rest before it can reach it targets.

```
location ~ ^/(?<path>.+)/(?<path2>.+)/(?<path3>.+)/(?<path4>.+)/.*$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$path/index.html@$query_string%2F$path%2F$path2%2F$path3%2F$path4 break;
}

location ~ ^/(?<path>.+)/(?<path2>.+)/(?<path3>.+)/.*$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$path/index.html@$query_string\%2F$path\%2F$path2\%2F$path3 break;
}

location ~ ^/(?<path>.+)/(?<path2>.+)/.*$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$path/index.html@$query_string\%2F$path\%2F$path2 break;
}

location ~ ^/(?<path>.+)/.*$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$path/index.html@$query_string\%2F$path break;
}
```

I tried with a directory called foo, in which I've put files called

- index.html@bar%2Ffoo
- index.html@bar%2Ffoo%2Ffoo2

when I access http://myserver/foo/?bar I get the file index.html@bar%2Ffoo, when I access http://myserver/foo/?bar I get the file index.html@bar%2Ffoo%2Ffoo2.

I let you adapt for image.php

Comment: This is not what I need, which is to regex replace slashes in the query string, not the location.  I have urls like http://example.com/foo/?bar=baz/quux which I need to map to files like foo/index.html@bar=baz%2Fquux

Comment: alright I understood it wrong then, sorry. I'll delete the answer